# Finding conditional expectation given another conditional distirbution

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation, uniform-distribution

Suppose $X$ is a uniformly distributed random variable on $[0,1]$ and given $X=x,$ a number $Y$ is chosen at random between $0$ and $x$. Suppose that you only know the value $y$ of $Y$ and you don't know $x$. We guess $x$ to be $\mathbb{E}(X|Y=y)$. Find this.

How would I start this?
This is what I did:
$Y|X \sim Unif(0,x)$.
So $$f_{X|Y}(x|y) = f_{Y|X}(y|x)f_{X}(x)/f_{Y}(y) \\ = \frac{\frac{1}{x}I_{[0,x]}(y)I_{[0,1]}(x)}{f_{Y}(y)}$$
and I'm stuck here.

Comment: It looks like you just need the denominator $f_Y(y) = \int_0^1 f_{Y|X}(y|x)f_X(x)dx$.  Also, while it does not say it, your equations suggest that, given $X$, we have $Y$ _uniformly distributed_ over $[0,X]$.

Comment: Thank you. Will the integral bounds simiplify to $[y,1]$ then?

Comment: Yes because $f_{Y|X}(y|x)=0$ if $y>x$.

Comment: Alternatively, you already know that, for every $y$ in $(0,1)$, $f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y)=c(y)\frac1x\mathbf 1_{y<x<1}$ for some constant $c(y)$ independent on $x$ hence, by normalization of $f_{X\mid Y}(\ \mid y)$,  $\frac1{c(y)}=\int_\mathbb R\frac1x\mathbf 1_{y<x<1}dx=\ldots$